# PHP array - Find values in keys and values

Tags: php, arrays, matrix

I have some data.

**First I have days, for example:**

1, 15, 30, 60, 90

**Then I have pricegroups, for example:**

simple, pro, elite, expert, nova

**Then I have costs (value numbers) for each pricegroup combined with days:**

```
$array = array(
  'day_1_simple' => 1000,
  'day_15_simple' => 2100,
  'day_30_simple' => 5600,
  'day_1_pro' => 900,
  'day_60_pro' => 1700,
  'day_90_pro' => 1900,
  'day_1_elite' => 10,
  'day_30_elite' => 200,
)
```

**Question(s):**

- How can I get all values from only day 1?
- How can I get all the values from only pricegroup pro?

Comment: One question: what did you try?

Answer (score 0):

You can construct your array with another way ?

```
$array = array(
    1 => array(
             "simple" => 1000,
             "pro" => 5600,
         ),
    15 => array(
             "simple" => 2100,
             "pro" => 12000,
         ),
);
```

If you can do this, then you can just use index or array function to find exactly what you need

Answer (score 0):

If you have php5.6 use `array_filter` function with `ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY` parameter:

```
$array = array();

// consider day 1 is _1_ in a key
$day_one = array_filter($array, function($k) {
    return strpos($k, '_1_') !== false;
}, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY);

// consider pro is _pro in a key
$only_pro = array_filter($array, function($k) {
    return strpos($k, '_pro') !== false;
}, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY);
```

This even can be reduced to single function:

```
$filter = '_1_';    // for example
$filtered = array_filter($array, function($k) use ($filter) {
    return strpos($k, $filter) !== false;
}, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY);
```

If your php is not 5.6 then do a simple **foreach**:

```
$array = array();
// consider day 1 is _1_ in a key
$day_one = array();
foreach ($array as $k => $v)
    if (strpos($k, '_1_') !== false)
        $day_one[$k] = $v;

// consider pro is _pro in a key
$only_pro = array();
foreach ($array as $k => $v)
    if (strpos($k, '_pro') !== false)
        $only_pro[$k] = $v;
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be as solution using `preg_match`, try this way to filter `day_1` and `pricegroup pro` array

```
$day_1=[];
$price_group_pro=[];
foreach (array_keys($array) as $key) {
    if (preg_match('/^day_1_/', $key)) {
        $day_1[$key]=$array[$key];
    }
    if (preg_match('/_pro$/', $key)) {
        $price_group_pro[$key]=$array[$key];
    }
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($day_1)
print_r($price_group_pro);
echo '</pre>';
```